# sql server - Using Datepart in where clause taking a longer time

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example :
Say We have a staging transaction table  which has 30 million rows, when joining with a master table which has unique (24 rows) ...each hours(1 to 24)

```
SELECT F.*
FROM STAGING_TRANSACTION F
     JOIN DIM_TIME DT ON  DATEPART(HOUR,F.RECORDED_TIME) = DATEPART(HOUR,DT.ON_TIME)
```

Datatypes are 
RECORDED TIME is DATETIME 
ON_TIME is decimal

There is no index on staging a, i have created index on dim_time since it was slow. When staging tabe is joined with other tables, it is faster but   when joined dim time, it takes a longer time. Index doesn't work since  a function is used in where clause.

is there any other way to make it faster

Leo

Comment: If you must do the join by the hour, the best way is to construct this in your tables, add to your staging table column "Hour" and also your DIM_TIME should have a "Hour" column. Once this is done you can join by the "Hour" column. Should be much more efficient.

Comment: That's because using `DATEPART` in a `WHERE`, or `ON` clause causes the query to become non-SARGable. This means that indexes won't be used when completing the query; and thus it will be slower. Functions like these should be avoided in the `WHERE` and `ON` clause.

Comment: if your table has 30M + rows, your current query will process all of them, cause you are not filtering your data with a where clause. Are you sure your join logic is correct? What is the target, and more: can you provide at least 1 row for both `STAGING_TRANSACTION` AND `DIM_TIME`?

Comment: STAGING TRANSACTION has each day and time level recording and dim_time is a one time loaded table with time key  for each 24  hours

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT F.*
FROM STAGING_TRANSACTION F JOIN
     DIM_TIME DT
     ON DATEPART(HOUR, F.RECORDED_TIME) = DATEPART(HOUR, DT.ON_TIME) ;
```

If you have `DIM_TIME`, you should have a column with the appropriate hour in the dimension.  After all, it is a utility table.  This is easily fixed:

```
alter table dim_time add dt_hour as (datepart(hour, on_time) );
```

Then, an index on this column will probably help the query:

```
create index idx_dim_time_hour on dim_time(dt_hour);
```

This should help the query:

```
SELECT F.*
FROM STAGING_TRANSACTION F JOIN
     DIM_TIME DT
     ON DATEPART(HOUR, F.RECORDED_TIME) = dt.dp_time;
```

You can also add a computed column to `staging_transaction`:

```
alter table staging_transaction add st_hour as (datepart(hour, recored_time) );

create index idx_st_hour on staging_transaction(st_hour);
```

Then the query looks like:

```
SELECT F.*
FROM STAGING_TRANSACTION F JOIN
     DIM_TIME DT
     ON f.st_hour = dt.dp_time;
```